# I imported a GLB file from Tilt Brush, and now the brush strokes look like ribbons. How can I fix this?

Tags: texturing

I imported a GLB file from Tilt Brush, and now the brush strokes look like ribbons.
How can I fix this?

I'm linking a YouTube video of how the brush strokes should look when zoomed in.
https://youtu.be/gVAa8H5IRWg

I'm also including a screenshot of my Blender workspace.

I was able to get the colors to show by changing the blend mode to 'Mix' instead of 'Multiply'.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out. I was able to upload the file directly to SketchFab on the TiltBrush/OpenBrush app and then download the GLTF file from SkecthFab. Apparently when you export to GLB on the app, it doesn't include the textures.

Comment: Hello, as I understand Blender had nothing to do with the mangled geometry, did it ?

Comment: @Gorgious - yep, it's an abstract painting/sculpture that I created in VR using Tilt Brush. I wanted to render it in a 3D program instead of taking screenshots from my Oculus.